# How does django insert a row into a database where one of the columns is NOT NULL?

Tags: django, postgresql

In the django admin I inserted a row by specifying 2 columns ( `firstName`, `lastName` ) and the `description` column had `blank=True` set.

I then tried mimicing this with fixtures because I have to import data from a legacy sql dump but I can't seem to avoid filling in a value for `description`. What is django doing different? Does it specify all columns and possibly specify an empty string or something that doesn't qualify as null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a form to populate a row, any inputs that are empty give `''`, so the fields get filled with an empty string rather than `NULL`.